# c# xamarin Error inflating class ActionMenuView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, tabs, android-actionbar

Hi i just tried making a Android aplication with xamarin and visual studio, and the thing i don't understand is how can i make a simple tabbed ui as seen in this [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv1LJ.png) I tried following the [Xamarin Creating a tabbed UI with TabHost Tutorial
(developer(dot)xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/tab_layout/walkthrough_creating_a_tabbed_ui/) 
but when i started the aplication it chrashed, then i tried it using actionbar and following this [Tutorial](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/tab_layout/actionbar/). I did everything step by step and got a "Error inflating class ActionMenuView".

Here Is my Code:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {

        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
        ActionBar.Tab Pudisoo = ActionBar.NewTab();
        Pudisoo.SetText("Pudisoo");
        Pudisoo.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.Pudisoo_selected);
        Pudisoo.TabSelected += Pudisoo_TabSelected;
        ActionBar.AddTab(Pudisoo);

        ActionBar.Tab Settings = ActionBar.NewTab();
        Settings.SetText("Settings");
        Settings.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.Pudisoo_selected);
        Settings.TabSelected += Settings_TabSelected;
        ActionBar.AddTab(Settings);
}
```

This is really frustrating, because i just need a simple app with 2 tabs and different buttons and textviews inside those tabs, but it just seems impossible for me. If someone could help me fix this error or tell me what am i doing wrong
i would be really happy.

I also did'nt find any (video)tutorials of creating a simple tabview.
so if you know a good tutorial you can send it to me,
thanks.

(i should also mention, that i am not very good ad programming yet)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are inside an activity derived from TabActivity, I use this method to 
add my tabs, and it works fine

```
addTab("home", "Simulator", typeof(SimActivity), Resource.Drawable.ic_action_simulator);
addTab("estimator", "Estimator", typeof(EstimatorActivity), Resource.Drawable.ic_action_estimator);
addTab("resources", "Resources", typeof(ResourceActivity), Resource.Drawable.ic_action_resources);
addTab("search", "Search", typeof(SearchActivity), Resource.Drawable.ic_action_search);
addTab("about", "About", typeof(AboutActivity), Resource.Drawable.ic_action_about);


Intent addTab(string keyName, string tabName, Type activityType, int resourceID, params Tuple<string,string>[] extras)
{
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityType);
  intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
  intent.PutExtra("key", keyName);
  foreach (Tuple<string,string> pair in extras)
  {
    string key = pair.Item1;
    string value = pair.Item2;
    intent.PutExtra(key, value);
  }

  TabHost.TabSpec spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec(keyName);
  spec.SetIndicator(tabName, Resources.GetDrawable(resourceID));
  spec.SetContent(intent);
  TabHost.AddTab(spec);
  return intent;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, my mistake, I see you want it in an ActionBar, i've done that also, digging up that code now.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem, you must set the

`ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;`

before setting the content

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        ActionBar.Tab Pudisoo = ActionBar.NewTab();
        Pudisoo.SetText("Pudisoo");
        Pudisoo.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.Pudisoo_selected);
        Pudisoo.TabSelected += Pudisoo_TabSelected;
        ActionBar.AddTab(Pudisoo);

        ActionBar.Tab Settings = ActionBar.NewTab();
        Settings.SetText("Settings");
        Settings.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.Pudisoo_selected);
        Settings.TabSelected += Settings_TabSelected;
        ActionBar.AddTab(Settings);
}
```

You missed the important part:

In the OnCreate method of an Activity – before initializing any UI widgets – an application must set the NavigationMode on the ActionBar to ActionBar.NavigationModeTabs as shown in this code snippet:

See this link for full example, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/tab_layout/actionbar/

Answer (score 0):

I was starting to give up already,

I got the problem fixed by using this code:

(i will just leave this here in case anyone has the same problem as me)

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{

    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    ActionBar.Tab Pudisoo = ActionBar.NewTab();
    Pudisoo.SetText("Pudisoo");
    Pudisoo.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.Pudisoo_selected);
    Pudisoo.TabSelected += Pudisoo_TabSelected;
    ActionBar.AddTab(Pudisoo);

    ActionBar.Tab Settings = ActionBar.NewTab();
    Settings.SetText("Settings");
    Settings.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.Pudisoo_selected);
    Settings.TabSelected += Settings_TabSelected;
    ActionBar.AddTab(Settings);
}
```